# Groovy JSON property Rename

Tags: json, groovy

I am using groovy json and want to replace the below key fields name . Please help me how to do .
{
"ID": "a3a98abd-e4a8-4667-81e4-123f641fd772",
"name" " "test"
"subProjects": [
{
"ID": "0c0f1a7d-4f5f-491f-a53b-7bdccd97407f",
"name" : "subproject"
}]

How can I replace the name of first "ID" to "ProjectID" and also position should not be changed ?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: My payload is like below 
var object = '{
   "ID":"a3a98abd-e4a8-4667-81e4-123f641fd772",
   "name":"test",
   "subProjects":[
      {
         "ID":"0c0f1a7d-4f5f-491f-a53b-7bdccd97407f",
         "name":"subproject"
      }
   ]
}' 
I tried below code
object.put("Project_ID" , "1234")
object.remove("ID")

but this code adds the element at the last and I want position shouldnot be changed . How can I basically replace keySet at the same position

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66905319/edit) the question if you have new insights.

Comment: You are changing data in a map - they are unordered/unsorted by default. The position of a key should have no meaning - especially if you deal with JSON.